# How to add item into listbox from background thread

Tags: c++, multithreading, winforms, user-interface, listbox

I have a thread that generates data and put it into external generator memory.
I wanna use ListBox as console analog and write some data from the thread like "data was put in channel 1 memory".

I do it straightforward way: (I'm using wide strings)

```
public: static System::Void WriteLog(const std::wstring str)
{
    String^ strOut = gcnew String(str.c_str());
    listBox1->Items->Add(strOut);
}
```

and just call WriteLog function from the thread, but it did nothing.
And I have strange feeling that my GUI didn't update.

Maybe there is a more elegant solution for mine objective?

Comment: This is not standard C++ because there is no `String^` (note the caret, which is a syntax error) in standard C++.

Comment: This is Managed C++ in .NET

Comment: sry i did not fully comprehend what you was said.
I'm currently using MS VS2017, with CLR Windows Forms.

I understand that I'm not use standart c++, hence there isn't windows forms.

And still, how i can do this console-like output in listbox?